Integrability with respect to intersection
I can't find any answer to this no doubt obvious question.
What does it mean to say that for a function $f$, $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha_1)\cap\mathcal{R}(\alpha_2)$.
I know that $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha_1)$ means that $f$ is Riemann-integrable with respect to $\alpha_1$, but how does an intersection make sense in this context?

Deem $\mathcal{R}(\alpha_1)$ and $\mathcal{R}(\alpha_2)$ as two sets of functions. So $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha_1) \cap \mathcal{R}(\alpha_2)$ means that $f$ is an element in $\mathcal{R}(\alpha_1)$ as well as an element in $\mathcal{R}(\alpha_2)$. In other words, $f$ is Riemann integrable with respect to both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Great, thanks. That's what I first assumed, but then I figured the Union notation would be much more suitable if that were the case, so I figured I was wrong.
